# Force content to flow horizontally

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm looking to force the content of a box that is dynamically centered vertically to flow horizontally instead of the usual vertical flow that will require scrolling up or down.

```
#outerbox {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

/* Creating 2% margin on left & right then 3% on top and bottom */
#innerbox {
    height: 94%;
    margin: 0 2%;
    margin-top: -47%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}

#content {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

---

```
<div id="outerbox">
  <div id="innerbox">
    <div id="content">
      Content goes here...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is when I resize the browser window, instead of flowing right and have horizontal scrollbars, the content moves down beyond the centered box. Advice on what I'm doing wrong and solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of creating a horizontally scrolling area with elements inside:

http://jsfiddle.net/6PupD/

The trick is the scrollable container has a width smaller than the object container. You will need to set the width of the object container large enough to hold all the elements.

Hope this helps.

Bob

Comment: This would actually require me to split the content into chunks in the markup. What I'm looking for is dynamically flow the contents right as the size of the content changes. This would be especially useful if the visitor increases the text size or changing content. I'm pretty sure CSS wouldn't be able to achieve this currently but hope that someone will point me to some javascript that does that